# How to use values 2 rows ahead or behind of current row in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dummy data table generated using the following code:

```
require("data.table")

x <- rnorm(12, 5)
dt <- data.table(x)
```

My version output looks like this:

```
             x
    1: 3.164381
    2: 1.572102
    3: 1.971536
    4: 3.311098
    5: 2.474029
    6: 2.637425
    7: 4.287430
    8: 1.134069
    9: 1.483923
   10: 1.842834
   11: 2.089589
   12: 1.786483
```

How would I create a "y" column that does the following calculation equivalent from excel, but in R using a data table?

= SUM(X(i) + X(i-1)) + MAX(X(i-2), X(i+1))

resulting in:

```
       x            y
3.164381       NA
1.572102       NA
1.971536       5.282634
3.311098       5.785127
2.474029       5.111454
2.637425       6.924855
4.28743        6.761459
1.134069       3.771494
1.483923       5.771353
1.842834       3.932423
2.089589       3.876072
1.786483       3.629317
```

Thanks

Comment: That `SUM` ist not necessary, you are already summing

Comment: I don't have it on my computer, but in the devel version of data.table (1.9.5) there's a new `shift` function which might be suited for what you're doing. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table

Comment: At the last line the result of y should not be NA since your are looking for x(i+1), which does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dt$x + lag(dt$x) + apply(cbind((lag(dt$x, 2)), lead(dt$x)), 1, max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
 dt$y = pmax(c(NA,NA, head(x,-2)), c(tail(x, -1),NA)) + x + c(NA, head(x,-1))
```